# Where Clause in Sql Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I Have A Table as Shown Below

```
number  unit  Value     
 78      m     ss
 74      km    aa
 77      m     ww
 77      km    ee
 77      km    ii
 74      m     pp
```

I am writing a Range Query to check unit and  get the nearest Values. i am using where condition to check unit and number.

```
  cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_DOF+" WHERE units = '" + unit + "' AND ABS("+inputNumber+" - number)=(SELECT MIN(ABS("+inputNumber+" - number)) FROM "+TABLE_DOF+") AND ABS("+inputNumber+" - number<=5", null);
```

If the input number is 79 and unit is km, then I will get empty row.

If the input number is 79 and unit is m, then I will get one row.

```
 number  unit  Value     
   78      m     ss
```

How I Want is if the Input number is 79 and unit is km then it should return me with in the range ie -5 and +5 of the given input number like the rows in below table

```
 number  unit  Value     
   77      km    ee
   77      km    ii
```

Any help will be Appreciated. Thank You

Comment: isn't this basically the third time you've posted a question about this query today?

Comment: Should it always return in range +-5 of input, or only in case there's no exact match?

Comment: Sounds like you nee a between clause

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821923/sqlite-query-select-query-with-between-clause

Comment: Ya Sorry about that but, i am new to this field and i am doing trial error to check the query, by the end of the day i need to complete this, so asking for help.

Comment: But they already gave you an answer on ranged query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927652/how-to-write-a-range-query-in-sqlite-android

Comment: @Kuba Spatny if i use that query i will get the value of 74 (79-5 = 74) which contains km as unit.. but i need only number 77 with km as unit.

Comment: then just add `AND unit = 'km'`, but you already have that part done here in the question text.

Comment: @Kuba Spatny by executing above Query with input number as 79 and unit as km it will return empty..

Answer (score -1):

i didnot understand your question completely, still as per my understanding
try this.

WHERE ((number>(inputNumber-5)) AND (number<(inputNumber+5))) AND unit='input unit'

Comment: should be `AND` and `number<(inputNumber+5)`. Also it may be better to use `BETWEEN`.